# how to validate multiple textbox for date using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The below code is used to validate start and end date(two textbox and date is selected from calendar)when a button is clicked.The code works fine.The problem is i have 8 more start and end date to validate.so can anyone tell me a common code to validate all the start and end date because of the code length.

```
function validated() {
   var cal1=document.getElementById('<%=EndDateTwo.ClientId%>').value;
   var cal2= document.getElementById('<%=StartDateTwo.ClientId%>').value;
         if (cal1 == '' || cal2 == '') {
                alert("Start Date and End Date  can not bleft blank.");
                return false;
            }
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
```

I am using html button to call this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2"  OnClientClick="return validated();" runat="server" Text="Enable" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method `validate(cal1, cal2)` an call this for each date pair you wan tto validate within the `validate()` method

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the element IDs into the function then you could reuse it for each pair of dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
function validated(){


 var EndDate1=document.getElementById('<%=EndDate1.ClientId%>').value;
 var StartDate1=document.getElementById('<%=StartDate1.ClientId%>').value;
  var EndDate2=document.getElementById('<%=EndDate2.ClientId%>').value;
 var StartDate2=document.getElementById('<%=StartDate2.ClientId%>').value;
//So on

   validatedCommon(EndDate1,StartDate1);
   validatedCommon(EndDate2,StartDate2);

//So on
}

function validatedCommon(cal1,cal2) {

         if (cal1 == '' || cal2 == '') {
                alert("Start Date and End Date  can not bleft blank.");
                return false;
            }
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
```

Comment: ..the code is working but the problem is when i call validatedCommon(EndDate1,StartDate1) on  a button click the  validatedCommon(EndDate2,StartDate2) is also begin called.